# PayPal Checkout (Smart Payment Buttons) - use own button

Tags: paypal, checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

Is it possible, to use the new paypal checkout (see: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) with a customized payment-button (without the smart payment buttons) as shown in following screenshot of an implementation?

Can someone maybe show me the Guide or some code, how to do the new paypal checkout without the smart payment buttons?

Reason: we do not want to break our design with the paypal buttons, but we want to provide the user with the same button for whatever payment method he selects.

[image: paypal-checkout from popular thomann.de shop]

Answer (score 1):

That screenshot may be the "Buy Now" [Smart Payment Button label](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/customize-button/#label), localized to German, with no additional payment option buttons showing.

Or it may an older [checkout.js integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/), where you can create your own button image